# Calculating precision and recall in R

Tags: r, precision-recall

Suppose I'm building a logistic regression classifier that predicts whether someone is married or single. (1 = married, 0 = single) I want to choose a point on the precision-recall curve that gives me at least 75% precision, so I want to choose thresholds $t_1$ and $t_2$, so that:

- If the output of my classifier is greater than $t_1$, I output "married".
- If the output is below $t_2$, I output "single".
- If the output is in between, I output "I don't know".

A couple questions:

1. I think under the standard definition of precision, precision will be measuring the precision of the married class alone (i.e., precision = # times I correctly predict married / total # times I predict married). However, what I really want to do is measure the overall precision (i.e., the total # times I correctly predict married or single / total # times I predict married or single). Is this an okay thing to do? If not, what should I be doing?
2. Is there a way to calculate this "overall" precision/recall curve in R (e.g., using the ROCR package or some other library)? I'm currently using the ROCR package, but it seems to only give me the single-class-at-a-time precision/recall.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a function for this purpose, based on the exercise in the book Data Mining with R:

```
# Function: evaluation metrics
    ## True positives (TP) - Correctly idd as success
    ## True negatives (TN) - Correctly idd as failure
    ## False positives (FP) - success incorrectly idd as failure
    ## False negatives (FN) - failure incorrectly idd as success
    ## Precision - P = TP/(TP+FP) how many idd actually success/failure
    ## Recall - R = TP/(TP+FN) how many of the successes correctly idd
    ## F-score - F = (2 * P * R)/(P + R) harm mean of precision and recall
prf <- function(predAct){
    ## predAct is two col dataframe of pred,act
    preds = predAct[,1]
    trues = predAct[,2]
    xTab <- table(preds, trues)
    clss <- as.character(sort(unique(preds)))
    r <- matrix(NA, ncol = 7, nrow = 1, 
        dimnames = list(c(),c('Acc',
        paste("P",clss[1],sep='_'), 
        paste("R",clss[1],sep='_'), 
        paste("F",clss[1],sep='_'), 
        paste("P",clss[2],sep='_'), 
        paste("R",clss[2],sep='_'), 
        paste("F",clss[2],sep='_'))))
    r[1,1] <- sum(xTab[1,1],xTab[2,2])/sum(xTab) # Accuracy
    r[1,2] <- xTab[1,1]/sum(xTab[,1]) # Miss Precision
    r[1,3] <- xTab[1,1]/sum(xTab[1,]) # Miss Recall
    r[1,4] <- (2*r[1,2]*r[1,3])/sum(r[1,2],r[1,3]) # Miss F
    r[1,5] <- xTab[2,2]/sum(xTab[,2]) # Hit Precision
    r[1,6] <- xTab[2,2]/sum(xTab[2,]) # Hit Recall
    r[1,7] <- (2*r[1,5]*r[1,6])/sum(r[1,5],r[1,6]) # Hit F
    r}
```

Where for any binary classification task, this returns the precision, recall, and F-stat for each classification and the overall accuracy like so:

```
> pred <- rbinom(100,1,.7)
> act <- rbinom(100,1,.7)
> predAct <- data.frame(pred,act)
> prf(predAct)
      Acc     P_0       R_0       F_0       P_1       R_1       F_1
[1,] 0.63 0.34375 0.4074074 0.3728814 0.7647059 0.7123288 0.7375887
```

Calculating the P, R, and F for each class like this lets you see whether one or the other is giving you more difficulty, and it's easy to then calculate
the overall P, R, F stats. I haven't used the ROCR package, but you could easily derive the same ROC curves by training the classifier over the range of some parameter and calling the function for classifiers at points along the range.

Comment: I think you got precision and recall code swapped. It should be r[1,5] <- xTab[2,2]/sum(xTab[2, ])

Answer (score 8):

As Robert put it correctly, [Accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) is the way to go. I just want to add that it is possible to do calculate it with ROCR. Take a look at help(performance) to select different measures.

For example, in ROCR only one decision threshold is used which is called *cutoff*. The following code plots accuracy vs cutoff and extracts the cutoff for maximum accuracy.

```
require(ROCR)

# Prepare data for plotting
data(ROCR.simple)
pred <- with(ROCR.simple, prediction(predictions, labels))
perf <- performance(pred, measure="acc", x.measure="cutoff")

# Get the cutoff for the best accuracy
bestAccInd <- which.max(perf@"y.values"[[1]])
bestMsg <- paste("best accuracy=", perf@"y.values"[[1]][bestAccInd], 
              " at cutoff=", round(perf@"x.values"[[1]][bestAccInd], 4))

plot(perf, sub=bestMsg)
```

which results in

[image]

To operate with two thresholds in order to create a middle region of uncertainty (which is a valid way to go if the circumstances / target application allows it) one can create two performance objects with ROCR

1. cutoff vs True Positive Rate (tpr) aka precision for the positive class
2. cutoff vs True Negative Rate (tnr) aka precision for the negative class

Select a suitable cutoff from the performance vectors (using the R method which) and combine them to achieve the desired balance. This should be straightforward, hence I leave it as an exercise to the reader.

**One last note: What is the difference between Accuracy and calculating precision for both classes separately and e.g. combine them in a (weighted) average?**

Accuracy calculates a weighted average, where the weight for class c is equivalent to number of instances with class c. This means that if you suffer a heavy class skew (98% negatives for example) on can simply "optimize" the accuracy by setting predict the label negative for all instances. In such a case a non-weighted plain average of both class precisions prevents the gaming of the metric. In the case of a balanced classes both calculation methods lead of course to the same result.